# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to echo out the name of the user in my article and I'm getting the

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object.
```

My codes:

**Offer Model**

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id');    
    }
}
```

**Country Model**

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Offer::class);
    }
}
```

**index.blade**

```
{{ $offer->countries->name }}
```

**OfferController**

```
public function index()
{
    $offers = Offer::latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.offers.index', compact('offers'))
```

when  I`dd($offer->first()->countries)` the result is null.

Comment: Try like echo "<pre>"; print_r($offers); die;

Comment: Also $offer is not a correct object, you are returning $offers

Comment: You might need to update your blade file like in foreach @foreach($offers as $offer)    {{ $offer->countries->name }} @endforeach but first check what's coming in your json string.

Comment: that "{{ $offer->countries->name }}" is inside a foreach loop

where to insert that print_r($offers)?

Comment: at the top of foreach to check

Comment: like <?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($offers); die; ?>

Comment: the output of App\Offer::first()->countries is null

Comment: it means nothing is coming from table or your query is not correct

Comment: You have defined your `Country` <-> `Offer` relationship as one-to-many.  That means the a `Country` has many `Offers`, but an `Offer` belongs to just one `Country`.  `$offer->countries` should return a single model, not a collection (and should be renamed to `country()` to avoid confusion).  Is the data in the DB really OK?

Comment: @AmitGupta No, that's eager loading, not 'joining`, and it just means data is requested from the DB more efficiently.  Skipping it will still load data, it just takes extra DB queries to do it.

Comment: Ok fine @Don'tPanic

Comment: is it intentional that you use `$offers = Offer::...` (notice the s) and then you `dd($offer->....)`?, please check your code for consistency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add foreach loop in your blade file like below:

```
@foreach($offers as $offer) 
{{ $offer->countries->name }} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: it's actually nested inside a foreach loop just like you did.

Comment: You can debug after $offers = Offer::latest()->paginate(5); as well

Comment: just add echo "<pre>"; print_r($offers); die;  after this

Comment: Can you tell me your table name?

Comment: data must come out of offers table. try simple query first like $offers = Offer::get();

Comment: try update like this $offers = Offer::with('countries')->latest()->paginate(5);

Comment: And then check with echo "<pre>"; print_r($offers); die;

Comment: country is coming or not from countries table

Comment: table name is offers

Comment: [relations:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [country] => 
                                )

is that what you wanted to check in print_r($office)

Comment: country is still coming as empty?

Comment: Yes but still country is coming as empty

Answer (score 1):

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    // try change countries to country, because it's one to one relation.
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);    
    }
}
```

then use optional when echo a relation

```
{{ optional($offer->country)->name }}
```

The optional function accepts any argument and allows you to access properties or call methods on that object. If the given object is null, properties and methods will simply return null instead of causing an error:

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.